# Set default umask for everything in Debian Squeese, included sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, umask, debian-squeeze

How can I change the umask for ssh and sftp in debian squeeze.

```
I have changed the umask from 022 to 002 in  
/etc/profile and  
/etc/login.defs 
and modified 
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server to 
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Everything seems to work when I am connecting through a shell, but I am still getting the wrong permissions when uploading files with through . Do you have any idea of how I can fix that issue?

I manged to solve the issue by following [How to setup ssh's umask for all type of connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections)

```
Added:
# Setting UMASK for all ssh based connections (ssh, sftp, scp)
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0027
in /etc/pam.d/sshd
and /etc/pam.d/login

I also reverted to 
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper script which sets the correct umask and execute that as instead of sftp

```
#!/bin/bash
umask 002
exec /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server
```

Modify the sshd_config

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/local/sbin/sftp-server.sh
```

Your sftp-server location may vary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to solve the issue before you got to answer so I am giving you and upvote for the effort. Thanks for helping out but I am not going to try your solution since I already got it to work. (I had to few points to give you an upvote :( sorry)

Comment: @user68802 What's your final solution then? You should add it here.