# Per-user umask over all ssh connections

Tags: ssh, pam, umask

Following on from [How to setup ssh's umask for all type of connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections)

Is it possible to do this on a per-user basis? Here's what I have at the minute:

*/etc/pam.d/ssh*

```
sesssion optional pam.umask.so umask=0027
```

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. The value set by `pam_umask` can be overridden by the user for interactive logins ([`man umask`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/umask))
2. `pam_umask` has provisions for per-user settings ([`man pam_umask`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_umask))