# How do I get a server side umask to be honored in scp -r when creating directories?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp, umask

I am trying to setup an scp receiver that allows select users, based on ssh keys, to scp files to a specific server as a user different than themselves.  This is to satisfy access restrictions by corporate figures. [8^) The ultimate setup would include a user's .ssh/config file having an entry like:

```
Host ssh-server
  HostName=my-ssh-server
  User=receiver
```

Their scp command would look simple like this:

```
scp /tmp/file.txt ssh-server:/some/dir/file.txt
```

I have been following a few of the questions about setting umask for scp, sftp, and ssh but I find that when creating directories, the umask is ignored and for permissions of created dirs and subdirs.  However file permissions are correct.

[One example of a question I have followed for the setup.](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections)

Here's what I have done:

1: Added the following to the receiver's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
command="/home/receiver/bin/bash_scp_run" ssh-rsa AAA ... My SSH Key
```

2: Wrote the script referenced above that sets umask to 027 and logs to a tmp file that it was executed.  I also tested without this script and the results did not show that the umask of 027 was set.  In fact it appeared that the default umask on this system was 002.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Entering ~/bin/bash_scp_run" >> /tmp/scp_log.txt
umask 027
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

3: Ran many tests including:  (Assume that all files and dirs locally have perms of 777 so the umask should be the only limiting factor.)

```
3.1: scp /tmp/file.txt ssh-server:/some/dir/file.txt
```

Result: /some/dir/file.txt has permissions of 750 just as expected.

```
3.2: scp -r /tmp/dir-with-subdirs ssh-server:/some/dir/top-dir
```

Result: /some/dir/top-dir has permissions of 777 which is not expected.
Also /some/dir/top-dir/subdir has permissions of 777 which is also not expected!
However files at any level have permissions of 750 which is expected.

In all cases the file /tmp/scp_log.txt showed that the umask was successfully set.

From the results in 3.2 it appears that the umask is not honored when scp creates directories but it is honored when it creates files!  From my long UNIX/Linux experience, that's not how umask is supposed to work.  This seems like an scp bug.

Comment: Is that on Linux or Unix by the way?

Comment: This is on Linux.  I've tested with CentOS 6.8 and 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `scp` switch you're looking for is "-p".

from `man scp`:

```
-p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.
```

So your command would look like:

```
scp -pr /tmp/dir-with-subdirs ssh-server:/some/dir/top-dir
```

I also think you should consider using `rsync` instead of `scp` because it verifies the integrity of the files it transfers and it also has the "-p" switch which preserves permissions of the source location files.

I usually use:

```
rsync -avzp /src/dir /trg/dir
```

Check this link to get a nice explanation about each switch and also it's a nice site to bookmark:
https://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-avzp+%2Ftmp%2Fsomedir+%2Fnew%2Flocation

Edit #1:

In that case, I suggest you add the umask command to the relevant user's `.bash_profile` (or any other shell start script) on the remote end machine because as far as I know, scp also runs the user's rc scripts when it is used.

Another thing you can do, which will affect all the users in the machine (Unless configured in a more complex way) is to use the pam module `pam_umask.so`.

The file where it should be configued would be:

```
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

If you want to limit this behavior to ssh sessions, you should add such a line:

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0007
```

Comment: The "-p" arg for scp or rsync will, like you said, preserve the source file permissions.  What I want is to have the permissions rewritten by the umask on the server side.  That's why all the effort to set umask on the server.  The intent is to provide access to only the owner and group on the destination.

Comment: I've looked at those options and decided that at least for this purpose, it is better to limit the ownership to a single user through use of public keys. The real issue here is that scp isn't honoring the umask even though I can prove that it is getting set correctly.  I'm wondering if there is maybe some setting in scp that I haven't found with an extensive search that would assure the umask gets applied to directories.

Comment: Turns out there was a bug in scp that caused the umask to be ignored.  I filed a bug against it and very shortly there was a validation that I was correct and a fix was submitted to resolve it!