# sftp-server set Permissions for all files

Tags: sftp

I have an sftp-server and need to set all files' permissions to 775 which upload from client.How can I do that? 
Just found the umask set,but it is not fit for me as client may upload file with 664 permissions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put desired umask with SFTP?](http://serverfault.com/questions/70876/how-to-put-desired-umask-with-sftp)

Comment: _"but it is not fit for me as client may upload file with 664 permissions."_ --> what do you mean?

Comment: umask just help you mask the client upload files' permissions like (0777 -> umask 0022 -> 0755).

Comment: But I want to set all files permissions like (chmod 644 upload_file)

Comment: You want 775 or 644?

Comment: Oh,sorry, just an example. 775 I want.

Comment: The permission on client has no mean when uploading to the server. Did you read the above link?

Comment: Yes I read it and test it on my server before.You know ,I had set umask to 0002 and If I upload an 777 file(A) to server , 775 A changed. I upload 666 file (B) , 664 B changed.So umask work to mask 0002 permission.Right?

Comment: And how can I set to make all files to 775 whatever the client upload?

Answer (score 0):

> And how can I set to make all files to 775 whatever the client upload?

You cannot.

```
Resulting permission = Default permission AND (NOT umask)
```

With file:

```
default permission = 666 = 110 110 110
umask                    = whatever
resulting permission     = xx0 xx0 xx0
```

In summary, you cannot create an executable file using `umask`.